# Run a schedule with python GTK

Tags: python, gtk

I'm building a GTK application with Python but I want to update labels at a specific time every hour.

I tried with [`schedule`](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) but apparently it doesn't work with pygobject. This is my sample code

```py
application = Application()
application.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
application.show_all()
Gtk.main()

print('go here') # This line never run
schedule.every(30).seconds.do(application.update_code)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

---

**Update** Thanks for the answer of JohnKoch, this solution was applied to [my repo](https://github.com/lioaslan/linux-authenticator) that works as TOTP Authenticator on Linux, You can visit and I will appreciate it very much if you leave a star or any issues about my repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Gtk.main()`

> Runs the main loop until Gtk.main_quit() is called.

So schedule below never has the chance to run. You need to hook a function to Gtk main loop, for example, by calling `GLib.timeout_add`.

Here is an example,

```py
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import GLib, Gtk

import schedule

window = Gtk.Window(title="Hello World")
window.set_default_size(600, 400)
window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

label = Gtk.Label(label="0")
window.add(label)
window.show_all()

count = 0

def update_label():
    global count
    count = count + 1
    label.set_text(str(count))

schedule.every(2).seconds.do(update_label)

def run_schedule():
    schedule.run_pending()
    return True

GLib.timeout_add(1000, lambda: run_schedule())

Gtk.main()
```